# Does forge allow user to integrate coordinate data from GIS platform?

Tags: gis, autodesk-forge

I am a student doing research on Forge, currently my team planned to build an indoor navigation by using coordinate calculated from GIS, the purpose of it is to guide visitor to the particular room in my department building. However, I can't find any solution from Forge API library. So, my question is, does forge provide a way to let us integrate coordinate from GIS?

Comment: "GIS coordinate"? There are no such thing. GIS software usually handles a lot of different coordinates. Do you mean GPS coordinates? So WGS84?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I am sorry about the misleading title, my purpose is using GIS to calculate the pathway in my department building.

Comment: To me, it is not yet clear what you are doing, and what it is the real problem. Note: I tend to see GIS just as a tool to visualize spacial data (e.v. also to analyze them, but often we use specialized tools/scripts for that). We have many other tools (to handle georeferenced data, databases capable to handle spacial data, visualization tools (e.g. web), and many other tools and libraries to handle such data). Your question is too generic. [In any case: GIS handle all coordinates, so you just tell GIS to convert coordinates to something suitable to Forge, just remember to use 3d data]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi my problem is on the Forge part, forge seem like didn't provide any API for us to integrate data from GIS, they only provided a very basic drawing pathway tool extension, but it only work on a single level building.

Comment: Autodesk uses e.g. DXF files, and many GIS tools can work (import/export) with that. But you are discussing API (which lacks in your question). You should have clear ideas on what you want to do, and write them on question. These are the rules of this site ("a reference site, not a forum"). If you want general ideas on how to do things, in general it is better to discuss in specialized forums (with a targeted focus). Note Autodesk has extensive documentation on the API

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks for your rectification, this is the first time I am using these kind of platform after I started learning coding. Anyway, thank you very much for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [GeolocationExtension](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/GeolocationExtension/) on your projects.
We use that, for instance on [Google Maps Locator](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/GoogleMapsLocator) for georeferencing our models.

You can also retrieve Geolocation from translated Revit models using [AEC Data](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api)

Comment: thanks for your help, but my aim is to built geolocation inside a building model (so that I can have an extension for indoor navigation, such as providing pathway from a room to another).  I have figured out possible solution, by using  [Add Custom Geometry](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/) with some modification, so that it can receive coordinate data from GIS platform.

Comment: Oh i see.
The sample below might be helpful
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/move-viewers-camera-along-drawing-travelwalking-paths-forge-viewer

Comment: thanks for helping, this is what I am looking for